# Unable to load Android image (ImageView) in emulator due to out of memory?

Tags: android, imageview

I am new to Android development and have encountered an error with loading an image into an activity.

The following is what I see from the log in eclipse:

```
04-15 19:55:36.316: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 53% free 2551K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 180ms
04-15 19:55:36.756: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 53% free 2550K/5379K, external 4025K/5027K, paused 42ms
04-15 19:55:37.296: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 53% free 2560K/5379K, external 5570K/5597K, paused 52ms
04-15 19:55:41.306: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 53% free 2579K/5379K, external 6677K/7260K, paused 43ms
04-15 19:55:41.685: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 53% free 2578K/5379K, external 9077K/11125K, paused 51ms
04-15 19:55:41.986: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 2580K/5379K, external 9377K/11777K, paused 41ms
04-15 19:55:42.695: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 53% free 2578K/5379K, external 13794K/15842K, paused 51ms
04-15 19:55:42.725: E/dalvikvm-heap(3317): 10181472-byte external allocation too large for this process.
04-15 19:55:42.766: E/GraphicsJNI(3317): VM won't let us allocate 10181472 bytes
04-15 19:55:42.766: D/dalvikvm(3317): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 2578K/5379K, external 13794K/15842K, paused 33ms
04-15 19:55:42.775: D/AndroidRuntime(3317): Shutting down VM
04-15 19:55:42.775: W/dalvikvm(3317): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.digitest.sample/com.digitest.sample.SafetyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at com.digitest.sample.SafetyActivity.onCreate(SafetyActivity.java:14)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     ... 11 more
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     ... 22 more
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
04-15 19:55:42.815: E/AndroidRuntime(3317):     ... 25 more
```

My image is a png image and is only about 130KB in size, although the dimension is 741x1526px. But I can't image why the emulator cannot handle such an image size. I loaded a smaller version of this image, which is about 120KB in size with a dimension of 370 × 762px and it is loaded just fine.

Here is how I implement the imageview activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/safety_base" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSafety"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgSafety_desc"  
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:maxHeight="180dp"  
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/safety_info_large" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you give the emulator enough memory when you created it?

Comment: I think some exception is causing the memory to drain out.It says it is in line 16 of some XML file.Can you check into the line 16 of the xml files you are using including the application manifest file

Comment: Also note that the image its file size isn't a good indicator for actual memory usage, as at runtime your images will be loaded as Bitmaps. Assuming you're using the default `ARGB8888` image format (4 bytes per pixel), it means your example file will actually take up 741 * 1526 * 4 = 4.523.064 bytes in memory (rougly 4,3 MiB). Low-end devices are likely to have problems granting such allocations, especially if you're trying to handle more than one such an image.

Comment: @Phix - I am using a generic AVD running API level 10 (code compiled in level 9), CPU?ABI is ARM (armeabi), SD card 1024 MB (but I am not using SB card access), built-in skin WVGA800, Max VM heap size 24 and RAM size is 256. I am hesitated to increase the heap size higher as I am worried that in reality when heap is on 24 (MB?) then I will run out of memory quickly.

Comment: @Krishnanunni - line 16 corresponds to the android:src="@drawable/safety_info_large" astatement which is when it attempts to load the png file...

Comment: @MH - the images actually were created by another developer for the iPhone version of the app so I am just reusing them. How do I find out if they are the default ARGB8888 format?

Comment: @Kenny: The default pixel format (the native one) is determined by the device's display; you can call [`getPixelFormat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getPixelFormat%28%29) to find out what its value is and compare against the [`PixelFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html) constants. However, as a solution you should try to either use a lower-res version of the current image, or, if possible, convert it to a 9-patch.

Comment: @MH - low res will not be a feasible option since I would like the app to function on a large screen tablet as well. As I am not familiar with the 9 patch format, is there a converter readily available so that I can convert my images to 9-patch format? I am adapting the images from another developer who created the original app for iPhone so I am reusing his png images.

Comment: *If* the image is suitable for '9-patching', then it should be fairly easy to convert it. The Android SDK comes with a [9patch tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html), but you can definitely use your favourite image editor too. If you need more examples, browse through the platform's resources (in your local SDK folder). Any ballpark on what the actual image looks like?

Comment: The app is a catalog of types of fish found in the local county so it consists of pictures of fishes as well as other informational materials in words and pictures. The aforementioned image is one of the informational pictures. There are about 50 images of fishes, each is 480x320 in dimensions and about 250 KB in size. Given this, I am not sure if the images are suitable for 9-patching.

Answer (score 1):

you gave width 1000dp and height 180dp. Reduce width or make it "fill_parent" or "wrap_content". Between, in which emulator have you tried?

Comment: please see my emulator config in my comments above

Comment: my response on emulator config pasted from above: I am using a generic AVD running API level 10 (code compiled in level 9), CPU?ABI is ARM (armeabi), SD card 1024 MB (but I am not using SB card access), built-in skin WVGA800, Max VM heap size 24 and RAM size is 256. I am hesitated to increase the heap size higher as I am worried that in reality when heap is on 24 (MB?) then I will run out of memory quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can over-ride the Activity's [onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onLowMemory%28%29) method for custom handling such scenarios.

Comment: My concern though is not about how to orverride this, but why I am hitting low memory already as I am just starting out with the project with 3 views and only a few images.

Answer (score 0):

Like Seshu said, keep your sizes realistic.  Having a 1000dp wide image with a screen nowhere near 1k dp is silly.  Check out the following from the dev guide for more info.

[Displaying Bitmap Resources](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

[Displaying Large Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

**EDIT**

Another alternative could be to load the image into a WebView for scrolling and zooming capabilities.

Comment: Actually, the width is 741px wide and height is 1526px. Ignore the setting of 1000dp in the layout_width since it was a leftover experimentation. I changed it to wrap_content and still got the OOM crash. The "long" image is necessary since the imageview will be contained in a scrollview so that the user can scroll up and down to see the info. The high res is preferred since there are quite a bit of embedded text and pictures in this image so we need to retain some readability.